# How does xarray broadcasting work with numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to do a coordinate transformation with my xarray coordinates so

I have a DataArray like:

```
d = xr.DataArray(np.zeros((10, 10, 1)), dims=['x', 'y', 'z']
```

and am doing operations like:

```
r = np.sqrt(d.x**2 + d.y**2 + d.z**2)
theta = np.arctan2(np.sqrt(d.x**2 + d.y**2), d.z)
phi = np.arctan2(d.y, d.x)
```

I get shapes of:

```
In [212]: r.shape
Out[212]: (10, 10, 1)

In [214]: theta.shape
Out[214]: (10, 10)

In [216]: phi.shape
Out[216]: (10,)
```

I would like to see the `(10, 10, 1)` shape that I get for r for all of them.

It looks like xarray's fancy broadcasting only kicks in for basic arithmetic operations and the numpy functions are broadcasting naively.

Is this correct?

Is there an approved way to get around this? I can write my own xarray aware arctan2 function which gets the broadcasting right, but I am hoping I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, NumPy functions generally don't do appropriate broadcasting on xarray objects. But xarray does come with wrapped versions of many of these functions, including `arctan2`, in the [`xarray.ufuncs` module](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#universal-functions). So `xarray.ufuncs.arctan2` should do exactly what you're looking for.